# Symfony Twig Rendering

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I am trying to bind variables with symfony template like `{{ 2ctc5qxi }} {{ !applianceType_page2_5 }}`. but i am getting error

> Unexpected token "name" of value "ctc5qxi" ("end of print statement" expected)

But it is working fine with keys, that does not starts with numbers & special characters.Please help in this.

Comment: variables can't start with number or special char, they should start with letter or underscore

Answer (score 3):

PHP variables can't start with a number. So make sure that name of variables is as per convention defined here.  [PHP Variables Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Answer (score 2):

Just rename your variable `2ctc5qxi` with something that starts with a letter or an underscore. Can't start with a number. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: `'[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'`.

Comment: Thanks i modified .

Comment: Cool, you should consider accepting one answer then :)

Comment: It is becomeing a trend not accepting any answer as valid in Stackoverflow. If this continuous I will stop answering questions.

Comment: Well...just new users probably not even knowing how SO works :)